# Alternative to template specialization when dealing with "nonexistent" / "optional" template arguments?

Tags: c++, templates, llvm

```cpp
template <typename SomeOp
          typename Intrinsic_U16, typename Intrinsic_U32, typename Intrinsic_U64,
          typename Intrinsic_S16, typename Intrinsic_S32, typename Intrinsic_S64>
struct GeneralMLIROpLowering {
  template <typename T>
  Value createIntrinsic(...) {
    return rewriter.create<T>(...);
  }

  void matchAndRewrite(SomeOp Op) {
    switch (getOpType(Op)) {
      case OpType::U16:
        createIntrinsic<Intrinsic_U16>(...);
      case OpType::U32:
        createIntrinsic<Intrinsic_U32>(...);
      case OpType::U64:
        createIntrinsic<Intrinsic_U64>(...);
      ...
      default:
        error();
    }
  }
}

using SpecificMLIROpLowering =
  GeneralMLIROpLowering<SomeIntrinsic_U16, SomeIntrinsic_U32, SomeIntrinsic_U64, ...>;

// What if in this case there isn't a U32 intrinsic?
using SpecificMLIROpLowering =
  GeneralMLIROpLowering<SomeIntrinsic_U16, NONEXISTENT, SomeIntrinsic_U64, ...>;
```

I'm working on an MLIR lowering pass and have a bunch of ops that lower in a similar manner, so I'm trying to generalize with a template. In some cases certain ops won't have intrinsics for all unsigned and signed 16/32/64 types; maybe one won't have intrinsics for base 32, and another only has intrinsics for unsigned.

What trips me up is that, to the compiler, all the types are still used in `createIntrinsic`, so I can't simply declare and pass in an empty dummy class as a template argument for `NONEXISTENT`.

However, I have guarantee that no one will ever try to call `matchAndRewrite` with an `Op` that leads to a nonexistent intrinsic in the switch case.

I'm sorry for how jank this sounds. Maybe I shouldn't be looking for some kind of dark magic to let me do this and should be using a different approach altogether, which I'm open to. Regardless, thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: I'd like to see a less 'pseudo-code' example so that I can properly get my head around what that the problem is.  Think [mre].

Comment: Template parameter pack? Sometimes it's easier to generalize than to solve a specific problem.

Comment: My first inclination is to specialize `callSomeFunc` for `NONEXISTENT` (for which I'd probably use `void`) to either do nothing or call `error()`

Comment: @PaulSanders still not quite reproducible, but I've edited the question so the use case is at least more clear.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I don't believe I can explicitly specialize that function without specializing the class first though?

Comment: Have it call a helper function outside of the class, and specialize that. It doesn't appear to depend on any of the class' template parameters.

Comment: The codebase I'm working with heavily discourages declaring helper functions outside classes they're relevant to. Is there any alternative?

Comment: With sufficiently modern compiler, you could use `if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, void>)` to put a special case directly into the body of `createIntrinsic`, without specialization.

Comment: I will try this. I've also found the possibility of overloading using a dummy template class as argument, so will try that too. Thanks!